# How can I make my textbox controls update when bound object is set to a new object in my View Model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I am new to WPF and I have encountered a problem on the project i am working on using the MVVM pattern (caliburn micro).

My problem is as follows. I have a collection of objects bound to a DataGrid and a selection of text boxes, combo boxes, check boxes,  ect, all bound to different properties of a single object of a different class - which i have called my input object.

[my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWJqO.png)

What I want is as follows: when i click my "Add" button, I want a new object to be added to my datagrid collection and my input object to be set to a new instance of this input object so that new values can be inputted and eventually added to my datagrid bound collection as well.

This works to some extent, when the program is run the first object can be added to the collection with no problems.

[First Object adds as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P75Hz.png)

However when i go to add subsequent objects I find myself having to enter all the values twice. The first time I enter the value it resets itself back to the default of a new object when the focus leaves this control, forcing me to have to enter it again - after which it does stay there.

[Attempt to change value - note value has not changed after the underlying object has been changed by clicking the add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSKmz.png)

[Value only changes to the new blank value when a new value has been attempted to be entered and the users focus leaves the text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twFdv.png)

[Remains the same after being entered again and can be added to the datagrid OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3HoZ.png)

In short, when I set my input object to a new object the values remain from the previously inputted object and only change to that of the new input object after I attempt to enter new values.

Here is the relavent XAML code:

```xml
    <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" Width="140" Text="{Binding Path=MyInputObj.WeightFloatInput, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" Width="140" Text="{Binding Path=MyInputObj.RunLabelInput, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyInputObj.MethodsArray}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path= MyInputObj.MethodStringInput, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path= MyInputObj.ReassayInput, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path= MyInputObj.StandardInput, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Content="Add" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding AddButtonCommand}"/>


        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="Weights"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="8" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Weights, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Method" Binding="{Binding ChosenMethodString, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" Binding="{Binding WeightFloat, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lot Number" Binding="{Binding JobNumber, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Run Number" Binding="{Binding RunLabel, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Reassay" Binding="{Binding IsReassay, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Standard" Binding="{Binding IsStandard, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

And here is the C# code from my ViewModel in its entirety:

```cs
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LIMS.old_code;
using LIMS.Models;
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace LIMS.ViewModels
{
    class AddWeightsViewModel : Screen
    {
        public class WeightInput
        {
            public string[] MethodsArray { get; set; }
            public float WeightFloatInput { get; set; }
            public string RunLabelInput { get; set; }
            public string MethodStringInput { get; set; }
            public bool ReassayInput { get; set; }
            public bool StandardInput { get; set; }

            public WeightInput(AddWeightsViewModel context, string number, bool RA, bool Standard)
            {
                MethodsArray = EnumHelper.enumToList(context.MyCard.MethodsRequired, typeof(labMethods)).ToArray();
                WeightFloatInput = 0f;
                RunLabelInput = number;
                MethodStringInput = MethodsArray[0];
                ReassayInput = RA;
                StandardInput = Standard;
            }
        }

        public BindableCollection<Weight> Weights { get; set; }
        private ShellViewModel mySVM;
        public Card MyCard { get; set; }
        public WeightInput MyInputObj { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddButtonCommand { get; set; }

        public ICommand SelectionChangedCommand { get; set; } // to be used later
        public ICommand OnDoubleClickCommand { get; set; } // to be used later
        public Weight SelectedWeight { get; set; } // to be used later


        public AddWeightsViewModel(Card card, ShellViewModel SVM)
        {
            mySVM = SVM;
            MyCard = card;
            Weights = new BindableCollection<Weight>();
            OnDoubleClickCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(HandleOnDoubleClick));
            SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(HandleSelectionChanged));
            AddButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(HandleAddButton));
            MyInputObj = new WeightInput(this, "1A", false, true);

        }

        protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
        {
            mySVM.AddWeightsVM = null;
        }

        #region command handlers
        public void HandleSelectionChanged(object obj) // to be used later
        {
            Weight weight = (obj as Weight);
            if (weight != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("selection changed " + weight.JobNumber.ToString());
            }
        }
        public void HandleOnDoubleClick(object obj) // to be used later
        {
            Weight weight = (obj as Weight);
            if (weight != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("double click " + weight.JobNumber.ToString());
            }
        }
        public void HandleAddButton(object obj)
        {

            var w = new Weight();
            w.JobNumber = MyCard.JobNumber;
            w.IsReassay = MyInputObj.ReassayInput;
            w.IsStandard = MyInputObj.StandardInput;
            w.ChosenMethodString = MyInputObj.MethodStringInput;
            w.WeightFloat = MyInputObj.WeightFloatInput;
            w.RunLabel = MyInputObj.RunLabelInput;
            Weights.Add(w);
            MyInputObj = new WeightInput(this, "1A", false, true); 
            MessageBox.Show("commited");
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help - I hope it isn't something too obvious I've missed - I have tried a number of different things with no luck so far.

Comment: Your "Viewmodel" must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the PropertyChanged event when the value of a property changes. Otherwise, it shouldn't be called a viewmodel; that's the key thing that viewmodels do. Here's a [simple example](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/). Also, show us how the viewmodel is created and how it gets to be the DataContext for the above XAML.

Comment: Thank you very much sir - I will look over this example and try and rectify my code! I've got a bad habit of watching or reading half a tutorial and then thinking I've got it all figured out! I will show you how i create the viewmodel and make it the datacontext... just as soon as i've figured out how to post code as a comment

Comment: 'var WinManager = new WindowManager();  AddWeightsVM = new AddWeightsViewModel(card, this); WinManager.ShowWindow(AddWeightsVM, null, null);' The window my question is regarding is opened from another window using this WindowManager class which I believe is a feature of Caliburn Micro

Comment: I'm not familiar with Caliburn Micro, though if they want you to pass viewmodels to UI element constructors, that bodes ill for their grasp of MVVM.  I also have no idea what `Screen` is or where that XAML is located. Is it located in the window, in a usercontrol, or what?

Comment: How is your DataGrid populated?

Comment: Thank you Ed - I've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged as per your example and now my program functions as I had intended. I had inherited that Screen class so that i can have only one instance of the window open at a time - It allows me to override that OnDeactivate method which is called when the window is closed. I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it with caliburn micro - i just wanted a quick way to open up a new window. It seems to work OK but no doubt requires some further looking into on my part.

Comment: My datagrid is populated by simply having the same name as my BindableCollection. Again - i have no idea if this is correct but it seems to work well enough so far. Thank you again for your help - It is greatly appreciated. As you can probably tell I'm no professional programmer - just a lab technician having a little dabble.